# Row number with lag event partition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to insert a row number that is partitioned by the previous flag.

I have tried using the lag function within the partition, but am having challenges with NULLs.

I can determine the different block of X's by multiple date differences determined by the LAG and LEAD function and other key flags. So each 0 in the LAG and LEAD columns indicate that the rows are "linked."

My table looks like this and I want the row number to restart at the second block of X's:

```
Person_ID  Event_flag  Row_number  LAG_datediff  LEAD_datediff  FLAG  FLAG2
A           X          1           NULL          0              1     NULL
A           X          2           0             40             NULL  NULL
A           Y          1           40            150            NULL  NULL
A           X          1           150           0              1     NULL
A           X          2           0             NULL           NULL  1
```

Comment: How do you know which is the 2nd block of Xs? There doesn't seem to be an ordering column we can use.

Comment: The `Person_ID` and `Event_flag` columns are not enough here. You must reference another column that represents the order of the rows, since database tables are unsorted by nature. For more information, read [The “Natural order” misconception](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/08/the-natural-order-misconception/)

Comment: "I can determine the different block of X's by..." That's just half the job. How do you know which row should get row_number 1 and which row should get row_number?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but its ordered by date...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an ordering column to number rows. It's difficult without sample data, but if your table is ordered by one `date` column, the next approach may help to get your expected results:

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    Event_Date date,
    Person_ID varchar(1), 
    Event_flag varchar(1)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   (Event_date, Person_ID, Event_flag)
VALUES
    ('20190910', 'A', 'X'),
    ('20190911', 'A', 'X'),
    ('20190912', 'A', 'Y'),
    ('20190913', 'A', 'X'),
    ('20190914', 'A', 'X'),
    ('20190915', 'A', 'X'),
    ('20190916', 'A', 'Y')
```

Statement:

```
;WITH ChangesCTE AS (
    SELECT
        Event_Date,
        Person_ID,
        Event_flag,
        CASE 
            WHEN Event_flag = LAG(Event_flag) OVER (ORDER BY Event_Date) THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END AS Change_ID
    FROM #Data
), GroupsCTE AS (
    SELECT
        Event_Date,
        Person_ID,
        Event_flag,
        SUM([Change_ID]) OVER (ORDER BY Event_Date) AS Group_ID
    FROM ChangesCTE
)
SELECT 
    Person_ID,
    Event_flag,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Group_ID ORDER BY Event_Date) AS Rn
FROM GroupsCTE
```

Output:

```
--------------------------
Person_ID   Event_flag  Rn
--------------------------
A           X           1
A           X           2
A           Y           1
A           X           1
A           X           2
A           X           3
A           Y           1
```

Comment: @MarcGuillot No, that will generate an arbitrary number for each row. That's not the order of the rows where created. You don't have to trust my word on this, you can also read Aaron Bertran's [Bad habits to kick : relying on undocumented behavior](https://sqlblog.org/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior) or any of the other links at the end of [The “Natural order” misconception](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/08/the-natural-order-misconception/).

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, I also don't want to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))` in this situation (as was suggested in the deleted comment). Using the appropriate column for ordering is very important here.